# UICollectionViewController: Memory used increasing when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have an iPhone app that displays a UICollectionViewController. The collection view contains cells that have a UILabel as subview.

Consider the following test code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return 500;
}
```

When I run the app and scroll up and down in the collection view the memory usage displayed in XCode 5s debug view (CMD-6) will increase steadily. Is this expected behavior or do I have a leak somewhere?

The `Collection reusable view identifier` in Interface Builder is set to `Cell`.

*Edit:*
I profiled the test app in Instruments and this is a deep copy of the call that seems to grow while scrolling:

```
Bytes Used  Count       Symbol Name
   1.01 MB      24.2%   24251       +[NSObject allocWithZone:]
 229.95 KB       5.3%   2774         -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
 173.25 KB       4.0%   2376          -[UIView initWithCoder:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980           -[UICollectionReusableView initWithCoder:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980            -[UICollectionViewCell initWithCoder:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980             -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980              -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980               -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                -[UICollectionViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                 -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                  -[CVTViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                   -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                    -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                     -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                      -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                       -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
 111.38 KB       2.6%   1980                        -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396        -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396         -[UIView initWithCoder:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396          -[UICollectionReusableView initWithCoder:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396           -[UICollectionViewCell initWithCoder:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396            -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396             -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396              -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396               -[UICollectionViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                 -[CVTViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                  -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                   -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                    -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                     -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                      -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
  61.88 KB       1.4%   396                       -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396       -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396        -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396         -[UICollectionViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396          -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396           -[CVTViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396            -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396             -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396              -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396               -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396                -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:]
  55.69 KB       1.3%   396                 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
```

(... Abbreviated ...)

Comment: Does it not stop to some upper bound?

Comment: Not that I could see. Scrolled from top to bottom and back for some minutes and memory usage went up slow but steady.

Comment: I have the same problem... @MarkGibson, is there any chance you've already found the answer?

Comment: Not yet, I am afraid :(

Comment: Could you find any solutions for this problem after a year?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `UICollectionViewAccessibility(SafeCategory)` has some form of bug in it that prevents cell reuse from working correctly.

See this answer for a better explanation: [UICollectionView do not reuse cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276509/uicollectionview-do-not-reuse-cells/19278032#19278032)

Also.. What device are you using for this issue to occur?