# iOS UICollectionView memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I've created UICollectionView through storyboard.
My cell is custom cell class that have 3 buttons with images.
My images are available as part of class GalleryItemInfo. I have an array of those objects

```
[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo
```

There is code for cellForItemAtIndexPath (in one cell there are three buttons for three items in array):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple *cell;

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 && !is_iPhone) {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellOrangeRed" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (is_Fingerprint_Version) {
            cell.imageViewRope.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-rope-1.png"];
        }
    } else {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellGreenBlue" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (is_Fingerprint_Version) {
            cell.imageViewRope.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-rope-2.png"];
        }
    }

    cell.previewCellDelegate = self;
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger leftPreviedId = [cell firstPreviewId];
    self.leftPreviewedID = leftPreviedId;

    UIImage *image1 = ((GalleryItemInfo *)[[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo objectAtIndex:leftPreviedId]).slotPreviewImage;
    UIImage *image2;
    UIImage *image3;

    if (leftPreviedId + 1 < [[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo count])
        image2 = ((GalleryItemInfo *)[[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo objectAtIndex:leftPreviedId + 1]).slotPreviewImage;

    if (leftPreviedId + 2 < [[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo count])
        image3 = ((GalleryItemInfo *)[[GalleryDataProvider sharedInstance].itemInfo objectAtIndex:leftPreviedId + 2]).slotPreviewImage;

    [cell setupWithImage1:image1 image2:image2 image3:image3];

    if (self.isEditModeEnabled) {
        [cell showRemoveButtons];
    } else {
        [cell hideRemoveButtons];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Trouble: when I scroll my collection memory usage increases every swipe from right to left on about 1 megabyte.

Why memory is not released?

**Update:**

CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple code (created through storyboard):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol UICollectionViewPreviewCellDelegate;


@interface CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSlot1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSlot2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonSlot3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRemove1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRemove2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonRemove3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewRope;


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UICollectionViewPreviewCellDelegate> previewCellDelegate;

- (void)setupWithImage1:(UIImage *)image1 image2:(UIImage *)image2 image3:(UIImage *)image3;
- (void)showRemoveButtons;
- (void)hideRemoveButtons;

- (NSInteger)firstPreviewId;

@end


@protocol UICollectionViewPreviewCellDelegate

- (void)collectionViewPreviewCell:(CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple *)collectionViewCell didSelectSubitemWithIndex:(NSInteger)subitemIndex;
- (void)collectionViewPreviewCell:(CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple *)collectionViewCell didEditModeRequestWithStatus:(BOOL)status;
- (void)collectionViewPreviewCell:(CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple *)collectionViewCell didRemoveRequestWithIndex:(NSInteger)subitemIndex;
- (void)slotButtonRequestsShadow:(UIButton *)slotButton;

@end
```

**Update:**

```
- (void)setupWithImage1:(UIImage *)image1 image2:(UIImage *)image2 image3:(UIImage *)image3
{
    [self.buttonSlot1 setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonSlot1 setBackgroundImage:image1 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    //if (image2) {
    [self.buttonSlot2 setBackgroundImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonSlot2 setBackgroundImage:image2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.buttonSlot2 setHidden:(image2 == nil)];
    //}
    //if (image3) {
    [self.buttonSlot3 setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.buttonSlot3 setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.buttonSlot3 setHidden:(image3 == nil)];
    //}
}
```

**Profiling**
[link for screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxR0U.jpg)

Comment: Add your cell code (`CollectionViewCellPreviewTriple`.

Comment: have you used instruments and leaks tool ? from what you describe i rather doubt it is leakage.

Comment: @SirJam show me implementation of this method - `(void)setupWithImage1:(UIImage *)image1 image2:(UIImage *)image2 image3:(UIImage *)image3;`

Comment: @ŁukaszTomaszewski , code has been added.

Comment: Run the profiler (Instruments) to find out what's creating all this extra data. It's most likely to do with the way you're creating the `UIImage` objects. How exactly are you loading those in?

Comment: @GuyKogus , my drawings stored in db. I load it throw MagicalRecord, then I init new object GalleryItemInfo withImage and push it in array.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the issue that many people have been suffering with where the cell's are not reused.

To test this, you should override the method `prepareForReuse` and in it write a very simple log:

```
NSLog(@"%@ is being called as expected.", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

You should then run your app, scroll the collection view, and check the console to see if this log appears.

If this log does not appear, you may want to [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276509/uicollectionview-do-not-reuse-cells/20147799#20147799) for help as to how to proceed. In my app cells are not reused in the simulator, but are reused on devices. It's odd.