# UICollectionView don't reuse Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UICollectionview in my UIViewController. On scroll collection view is not reusing cell. You can see **numberOfItemsInSection** method;

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return 7

    }
```

And this is the **collectionViewLayout** method;

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if(collectionView == mainCollectionView){
            switch(indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.20)
            case 1:
                return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width * 0.5) - 3, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            case 2:
                return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width * 0.5), height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            case 3:
                return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            case 4:
                return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width * 0.6) - 3, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            case 5:
                return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width * 0.4), height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            case 6:
                return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width), height: self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
            default:
                return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            }
        }
    }
```

The last one is **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if(collectionView == mainCollectionView){
            var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainCollectionViewCell

            switch(indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            case 1:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            case 2:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = false
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            case 3:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
            case 4:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            case 5:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = false
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            case 6:
                cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
                cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = true
                cell.placeLabel.hidden = true
                cell.lineView.hidden = false
            default:
                break
            }
            return cell
        }
```

Also you can see the output:

[image: CollectionView Image]

I have added a breakpoint to **case6** bot it is not entering that case. Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: change the Switch condition if there are 7 number of cells then use this switch((indexPath.row) % 7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView do not reuse cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276509/uicollectionview-do-not-reuse-cells)

Comment: Maybe the 7th item is out of the bounds of the screen, maybe you need to scroll a bit for the UICollectionView to load up that view?

Comment: I am scrolling the bottom to call the cellForItemAtIndexPath method but it is not reusing the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading UICollectionView data in the main thread solved my problem. I used:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    mainCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
```

Comment: ...can you please elaborate how that can help on OP?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's a good idea to handle each case like that.

You should create a wrapper object containing your cells parameters.

In your case, it should look something like the following :

```
class YourWrapperObject {
  var image: UIImage
  var clockIconHidden: Bool
  var size: CGSize
  // Your other vars
}
```

create an array of those objects (in your `viewDidLoad` method for example), then, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  var cell = /*get your cell using reusable identifier*/
  let cellParameters = yourObjectArray[indexPath.row]

  /* Then assign each parameters */
  cell.imageView.image = cellParameters.image
  cell.clockIconImageView.hidden = cellParameters.clockIconHidden
  cell.pinIconImageView.hidden = cellParameters.pinIconHidden
  cell.placeLabel.hidden = cellParameters.placeHidden
  cell.lineView.hidden = cellParameters.lineHidden

  /* return your cell */
  return cell
}
```

as well as in your `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
return yourObjectArray[indexPath.row].size
```

Your code will be much more readable and flexible

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will consider it. But this is not the answer of my question.

Comment: Using this code, your cell should be reused the way you want them to. Let me know if this is not the case